# Injected SolrTemplate Resource not connected to HttpSolrServer

Tags: java, spring, solr, spring-boot, spring-data-solr

I am using Spring data Solr 1.4 with a custom repository feature to try to implement a count function as per this article: [link](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/solr/spring-data-solr-tutorial-adding-custom-methods-to-a-single-repository/)

I am using Solr configured to use multiple cores.  My regular repository interface gets and uses the correct `SolrTemplate` and `SolrServer` instances, but the custom repository does not get the same instance of the template. In addition to using the `@Resource` to inject the bean, I have also tried getting the spring application context and pulling the bean from it. In both cases I am getting a `solrServer` bean reference that does not know what my core is, so the query fails when it tries to reach solr at: http://localhost:8983/solr instead of http://localhost:8983/solr/myCore

The bean definition looks like this:

```
@Bean
@Scope(value=ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_SINGLETON)
public SolrServer solrServer() {
    SolrServer server = new HttpSolrServer(solrServerUrl);
    return server;
}

@Bean(name = "solrTemplate")
@Scope(value=ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_SINGLETON)
public SolrTemplate solrTemplate(SolrServer server) throws Exception {
    SolrTemplate template = new SolrTemplate(server);
    template.setSolrCore(mainCore);
    return template;
}
```

And my test looks like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = SearchEngineApplication.class, loader=SpringApplicationContextLoader.class)

public class MainRepositoryTest {

@Autowired
private MainRepository mainRepository;
...
    @Test
    public void testCountResults(){
        long count= citcMainRepository.count("red");
        System.out.println("Found " + count + " results for the term red" );
        assertTrue(count > 0);
    }
}
```

The test always fails:

```
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /solr/select
```

When the proper url it should be reaching is `/solr/select/myCore`

Any suggestions as to what I might have misconfigured here? 
Any/all replies appreciated!

-- Griff

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem myself by creating a second bean of the same type and adding a qualifier to it.

In my SolrContext I defined the bean factory and bean definition as such:
    @Bean
    public SolrServerFactory solrServerFactory() {
        return new MulticoreSolrServerFactory(new HttpSolrServer(solrServerUrl));
    }

```
// SolrTemplate for /solrServerUrl/mainCore
@Bean(name = "mainTemplate")
public SolrTemplate mainTemplate() throws Exception {
    SolrTemplate solrTemplate = new SolrTemplate(solrServerFactory());
    solrTemplate.setSolrCore(mainCore);
    return solrTemplate;
}

@Bean(name="mainRepo")
public MainRepository mainRepository() throws Exception {
    return new SolrRepositoryFactory(mainTemplate())
            .getRepository(CITCMainRepository.class,
                    new MainRepositoryImpl(mainTemplate()));
}
```

Then by qualifying the Repository in my UnitTest as such:

public class CITCMainRepositoryTest {

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier(value="mainRepo")
private MainRepository mainRepository; 

@Test
public void testFindByLastName() {
    List<SearchResponse> searchItems= mainRepository.findByLastName("Hunt");
    assertTrue(searchItems.size() > 0);
}
...
```

}

Hope this helps someone else.

-- Griff